# Application startup exception When Run DotMemory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, memory-leaks, dotmemory

I am beginner to work with memory leak profilers.
I want to run dotMemory profiler, but when I choose:"run startup project memory profiling" item, I see this exception in command prompt window, and jetbrains window show profiling session has finished!
how can I fix this issue. please help me to run it correctly ...

```
   Application startup exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: D:\Projects\Source\PishroPostCloudLoyalty\pishropost-core\Yara.PedEx.Administration\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\wwwroot\
       at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
       at Yara.PedEx.Administration.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, PedExDbContext dbContext) in D:\Projects\Source\PishroPostCloudLoyalty\pishropost-core\Yara.PedEx.Administration\Startup.cs:line 155
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
    Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: D:\Projects\Source\PishroPostCloudLoyalty\pishropost-core\Yara.PedEx.Administration\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\wwwroot\
       at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
       at Yara.PedEx.Administration.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, PedExDbContext dbContext) in D:\Projects\Source\PishroPostCloudLoyalty\pishropost-core\Yara.PedEx.Administration\Startup.cs:line 155
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
       at Yara.PedEx.Administration.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Projects\Source\PishroPostCloudLoyalty\pishropost-core\Yara.PedEx.Administration\Program.cs:line 23
```

Comment: What is "Yara.PedEx"? Is it an application you tun under profiler?

Comment: yes exactly, it does not find some file, but i dont know why?

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem and I want to share it with you.
I did not have wwwroot folder in debuge/bin path, so I copy that to this path, and now I can use dotmemory :)